# looping a javascript object inside a loop of custom object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, object

First of all I'm beginner in javascript. I have this data **data.responseJSOn.errors** -

[image]

Currently I'm displaying the errors like this way -

```js
var errors =  data.responseJSON.errors;
    
console.log(errors);

errors.title && 
errors.title.forEach(function(messageText) {
    displayError(messageText);
    });

errors.message && 
errors.message.forEach(function(messageText) {
    displayError(messageText);
});
```

How can I display errors from there by using single code instead of predefined errors.title or errors.message.

**expected code like -**

```js
var errors =  data.responseJSON.errors;
var list = ["title", "message"];

list.forEach(function(item) {
    errors.item && 
    errors.item.forEach(function(messageText) {
        displayError(messageText);
    });
});
```

How can I fix it to get output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something more generic regardless of the key names in object `data.responseJSON.errors`

```
var errors =  data.responseJSON.errors;
var list = ["title", "message"]; // valid keys for which we need to show message

for (key in errors) {
  // check if key is valid and is array
  if(list.includes(key) && Array.isArray(errors[key])) {
    errors[key].map((msg) => {
        displayError(msg);
    })
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case you're going to need the `[]` syntax to access a field of the `errors` object with the value of a variable:

```
var errors =  data.responseJSON.errors;
var list = ["title", "message"];

list.forEach(function(item) {
    errors[item] && 
    errors[item].forEach(function(messageText) {
        displayError(messageText);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the respective property using `[]`:

```
var errors =  data.responseJSON.errors;
var list = ["title", "message"];

list.forEach(function(item) {
    errors[item] && 
    errors[item].forEach(function(messageText) {
        displayError(messageText);
    });
});
```

Otherwise (and as a better alternative), you can use [the `for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) syntax to access enumerable object properties:

```
var errors =  data.responseJSON.errors;
var list = ["title", "message"];

errors.forEach(function(error) {
    for (property in error) {
        displayError(error[property]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

here you don't have to explicitly mention the type of keys the error message has. Even in future, if `messages` and `title` changes you don't have to modify the code again.

```
const messageText = (message: string) => {
  console.log('message', message)
}

Object.keys(response).map((error) => response[error].length && response[error].forEach((message: string) =>  messageText(message)));
```